# Unsure about ANOVA usecase/design

Tags: anova

I am working on a project where 8 subjects ran with 2 different shoes at 3 different speeds. The way the different shoes at different speeds influence certain gait parameters is being observed (not individual variability). So i wanted to go for a two-way ANOVA. The issue i run into is that if i throw lets say the peak vertical ground reaction force values of all the steps of all subjects with shoe 1 / speed 1 into one pool wouldnt that violate the assumption of independance? Since one step might influence the next; steps from the same subject are likely not independent. What would your take on this be? Can i just look at the steps as independant events or not?

The other possibility would be to use a subjects average values over the steps for a certain parameter, but with 8 subjects that would have me end up at 8 datapoints.

Comment: As a first attempt to model the dependence between steps taken by the same subject, it could be enough to assume that any too steps (within subject) are equally correlated. Have you considered a mixed model (eg. model with random subject effects) or generalized least squares (eg. model with explicitly specified within-subject correlation structure)?

Comment: Yes, i went with a mixed model in the end!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP answered it in a comment